# How do I describe this particular scene?

Tags: fiction, description, narrative

My character lives in a war torn country. I'm trying to start this short story with him waking up on his way to school (possibly the bus stop). On his way, he sees graffiti, vandalism (basically thrashed cars and windows), bullet shells, etc. lying around everywhere. I'm writing this in first person and have yet to actually figure out how to put everything together. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question, in my opinion, 
leans towards 'what to write' which is not on topic for this site.

Comment: Sorry about that, but I'm actually looking for more of a "how" then a "what" in this particular case. Where would you advise posting it?

Comment: Whether it is "what to write". or "how to write", you are very close to asking someone to write your story for you. I am afraid that the only advice which you can expect is: "find words, then put them in sentences, then read and edit, until you are satisfied with the results". The craft of writing is not that different of all other crafts, in order to learn how to write, one must practice. It looks like you already have a picture in your head--just describe what you see.

Answer (score 4):

You describe very well what the main character sees.

Next, how do they feel about what they see?
What is new? Old?
What has changed since yesterday/ever? What has not?
Do they wonder Why? Who? When?
How are they connected to the scenes/environment they experience?
Is there anyone else with them; what do they say?
Do they contrast/agree with what the main character experiences?

...